# uv image editor alpha?

Tags: image, transparency

So I made an image in the uv image editor thats really simple (really just a line) and when I made the new image I checked the alpha box. but the background is simply black. Is there a way to make a new image in the uv editor that is nothing but the alpha to start with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using alpha channel of generated images for cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/using-alpha-channel-of-generated-images-for-cycles)

Answer (score 4):

When creating a new image in the *UV Image Editor*, change the *Alpha* channel of the *Color* to be 0. Then be sure that the *Alpha* check box is checked.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I feel like a noob for not knowing that.

Answer (score 1):

Wait, nevermind, I made a new image, and where the color is originally black, I see theres an alpha slider.

Comment: good for you, you figured it out before I finished my answer.

Comment: :) the answer you gave was a LOT more easier to understand