# alpha channel in image when compositing in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have two images that i'd like to overlay, the picture that is above is a point density picture that i saved in png so that it would support alpha channel,when saving it i could see that in color view it had managed to have the point density, but turned black when i saved it,but i think it still has the alpha channel in it. What node settings should i make to the alpha/transparency to be seen. this is how far i have come with my settings but i don´t know what else i should do.[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/using-alpha-channel-of-generated-images-for-cycles?rq=1

Comment: Don't use PNG, use OpenEXR to save the image with alpha. Re-read the comments on the [previous question you asked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128740/point-density-and-transparent-background)

Comment: read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background/44148#44148 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46606/cycles-transparency-results-in-color-loss-when-background-is-black/46815#46815 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles/41598#41598 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824